# loop through siblings with a specific class in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework

i have `tr`  class firstrow and `tr` class called addrows . addrows class is always after the firstrow class, i want to count the number of addrow tr's after each firstrow tr . in my example it should be 1 and 6 . this is my code .

```
<table id="sdx-O_BAR_added" class="roomtypeadded">
<tbody>
<tr class="header">
</tr>
<tr class="header">
</tr>
<tr class="firstrow">
</tr>
<tr class="addrows">
</tr>
<tr class="header">
</tr>
<tr class="header">
</tr>
<tr class="firstrow">
</tr>
<tr class="addrows">
</tr>
<tr class="addrows">
</tr>
<tr class="addrows">
</tr>
<tr class="addrows">
</tr>
<tr class="addrows">
</tr>
<tr class="addrows">
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

i have no idea how to this , i tried with jquery `siblings()` and `next()` . but coud not do it  , please help . :(

Comment: Is it just the actual number you want, or do you want to have the set of matching elements returned as well?

Comment: yap . i need to rerturn the matched elements . thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the `$.nextAll()` function:

```
$('table tr.firstrow').nextAll('tr.addrows').length;
```

This will give you the total count of all rows that follow a `tr.firstrow` element.

If you want to get an array of each `tr.firstrow`'s following .addrows class elements, you'd probably find jQuery's `$.map()` function more useful:

```
var counts = $('table tr.firstrow').map(function(){
    return $(this).nextUntil(':not(.addrows)').length;
});
```

This will return an array of numbers - effectively subtotals (e.g. [1, 6]).

Answer (score 0):

Try $("firstrow").each()
inside this function try doing $(this).next()

Answer (score 0):

this should work.

```
$("tr.firstrow").siblings("tr.addrows")
```

Comment: nop . i think this will return all the rows with class addrows , sory that's not the thing i wanted